# resume doesn't format well

Tags: formatting, itemize, enumitem, geometry, cv

So here is the [link](http://pastebin.com/neWt7Y79) to tex file of my resume

and here is how it is shown:
[image]

As you see, things like Research and Honors and Awards are clipped. Anyway you can help me to fix it?

Comment: The three most obvious problems (besides the missing braces) are: (1) your settings for `geometry` make little sense; (2) your `\LHEAD` command should not be put in a list as an `\item`; and (3) you are coding as if spaces aren't important in macro definitions, but they can be very important. (1) and (2) combine to cause the problems in the left margin; the effects of (3) would require more than a cursory glance at your document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is the best way to correct your code but at last I think it is a possibility to learn something about LaTeX.  Please check the documentation of the used packages, for example `geometry` with `texdoc geometry` on your terminal / console.  One hint: I would not use personal datas in the examples here ...

I checked you code and changed it a little bit.  I added `\usepackage{showframe}` to visualise the resulting typing area and margins.  Comment it out for a final print.

The major errors are:

```
\renewenvironment{itemize}{%
    \begin{list}{}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0.25em}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parsep}{0.25em}
    }%
}{%
    \end{list}
}
```

Please see the added `%`.  If you omit them (they were missing in your code) your macro code does not work.

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5in, top=0.75in}
```

I changed your `geometry` settings to get a better typing area (visualised with `showframe`)

```
\vspace{0.015\textwidth}
\hrule
\vspace{0.055\textwidth}% longer so that the rule is above the headline languages
\LHEAD{Langauges}%        out of itemize
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Persian}: Native
    \item \textbf{English}: Fluent
    \item \textbf{French}: Intermediate
    \item \textbf{Italian}: Familiar
    \item \textbf{Arabic}: Familiar
\end{itemize}
```

I put your command `\LHEAD` out of ìtemize. So you have no empty line at the beginning of `itemize` and the headings is in the margins as wanted.  But that makes the rule too close to the heading, so I used `0.055` insted of your `0.015`.

You should pretty print your code for a better readability as I did on some code parts to show the difference.

And remember the missing bracket around a few `\href` commands.

I personaly would use class `moderncv` for the cv.  There are still some things in your cv that could be better done but with the showed changes it compiles.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5in, top=0.75in}

\def\name{\color{blue}\href{http://www.linkedin.com/pub/mona-jalal/40/2/3b4}{Mona Jalal}}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    urlcolor = blue,
    pdfauthor = {\name},
    pdfkeywords = {CV, Mona Jalal, Electrical and Computer Engineering, University of Wisconsin-Madison},
    pdftitle = {\name: Curriculum Vitae},
    pdfsubject = {Curriculum Vitae},
    pdfpagemode = UseNone
}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
%\markright{\name 's CV, Last Updated: \today}
\thispagestyle{empty}
% Don't indent paragraphs.
\setlength\parindent{0em}

\renewenvironment{itemize}{%
    \begin{list}{}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0.25em}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parsep}{0.25em}
    }%
}{%
    \end{list}
}


\begin{document}

\reversemarginpar 
\setlength\marginparwidth{0.8in}
\newcommand{\LHEAD}[1]{\leavevmode\marginpar{\large\scshape#1}}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        437 N Frances, Apt 636\\
        Madison, WI, USA\\
        P.O.BOX: 53703
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
            & Cell Phone: (+1) 608 \\
            & E-mails: \href{mailto:jalal@cs.wisc.edu}{jalal@cs.wisc.edu}  \\
    \end{tabular}

\vspace{0.015\textwidth}
\hrule
\vspace{0.055\textwidth}
\LHEAD{Education}
\begin{itemize}
\item \large \textbf{Graduate Studies in Computer Sciences} \normalsize \\
    \begin{tabular}{cl}
        & \emph{University of Wisconsin-Madison}, Madison, WI, USA.
    \end{tabular}
    \item \large \textbf{M.Sc. in Electrical Engineering} \normalsize \\
    \begin{tabular}{cl}
            & \emph{University of Wisconsin-Madison}, Madison, WI, USA.\\
      & Graduated in August 2014.
        \end{tabular}
    \item \large \textbf{M.Sc. in Computer Engineering} \normalsize \\
        \begin{tabular}{cl}
      & \emph{Sharif University of Technology}, Tehran, Iran.\\
      & Major in Computer Architecture.\\
        & GPA: 17.78 out of 20\\
        & Graduated in August 2011.
        \end{tabular}
    \item \large \textbf{B.Sc. in Computer Engineering} \normalsize \\
        \begin{tabular}{cl}
        & \emph{Shahid Beheshti University}, Tehran, Iran.\\
        & Major in Computer Hardware.\\
            & Second best Hardware Engineering student\\
            & Graduated in August 2009.
        \end{tabular}
\end{itemize}

\vspace{0.015\textwidth}
\hrule
\vspace{0.055\textwidth}
\LHEAD{Research Interests}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Big Data Mining, Analytics and Systems, Database Management 
    Systems, Internet of Things, Social Network Data Analysis, 
    Machine Learning, Data Integration, Web Design, Distributed Systems 
    and Cloud Computing, Human-Computer Interaction, Computer Architecture, 
    High Performance Computing, Reconfigurable Computing, Digital System Design, 
    VLSI-CAD Design, Fault-tolerant Embedded Systems, Kernel Hacking, 
    Software Prototyping
\end{itemize}

\vspace{0.015\textwidth}
\hrule
\vspace{0.055\textwidth}
\LHEAD{Honors \& Awards}%}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Awarded Anita Borg Institute scholarship for attending 
     \textbf{GHC15} Grace Hopper Celebration of Women in Computing, 
      Houston, TX, Summer 2015.
  \item Awarded \textbf{\href{https://mlh.io/}{Major League Hacking}} 
    travel scholarship for attending \textbf{mHacks6}, University of 
    Michigan, MI, Summer 2015.
  \item Awarded Google travel scholarship to attend \textbf{VLDB15} 
    Very Large Databases conference, Hawaii, Summer 2015.
  \item Awarded travel scholarship to attend \textbf{TACC} 
    Supercomputing Summer Institute, Summer 2015.
  \item Awarded full CS departmental funding for attending 
    \textbf{Grace Hopper Celebration of Women in Computing} 
    ({\href{http://gracehopper.org/}{GHC’14}}), Summer 2014.
  \item Received the scholarship to attend IEEE BigData 2014 Conference 
    and First Hands-On Workshop on Leveraging High Performance Computing 
    Resources for Managing Large Datasets 
    ({\href{https://www.tacc.utexas.edu/news/events/2014/ieee/managing-large-datasets}{IEEE BigData'14}}), 
    September 2014
  \item Awarded travel scholarship to attend \textbf{\href{http://www.hacktech.io}{HackTech}}-the biggest hackathon in west coast- in December 2013.
        \item \textbf{Apple} and \textbf{Google Anita Borg} Scholarship recepient for attending \textbf{Grace Hopper Celebration of Women in Computing} (GHC’13) among 900 applicants, Summer 2013.
        \item Admitted and awarded the travel scholarship to attend the \textbf{\href{http://cra-w.org/ArticleDetails/tabid/77/ArticleID/55/Graduate-Cohort-Workshop.aspx}{CRA-W} Graduate Cohort Workshop} \textbf{CRA-W} in Boston, MA, Spring 2013.
        \item Offer of Admission to Electrical and Computer Engineering Graduate Program, by University of Wisconsin-Madison
ECE Graduate Admission, March 2011.
        \item Offer of Admission to Computer Engineering Graduate Program, by Shahid Beheshti University Brilliant Office,
September 2009.
        \item Ranked \textbf{2nd} among Graduated Students of Hardware Engineering, Class 2009.
        \item Accepted in the first round of National \textbf{Persian Literature} Olympiad, 2004.
        \item Admitted to attend \href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Organization_for_Development_of_Exceptional_Talents}{NODET} highschool (National Organization for Development of Exceptional Talents--designated for top 5\% of the entire high school students in the country), July 2001
        \item Ranked second among all the middle school students in math olympiad contest in Tehran , 2000.
        \item Ranked second among all the middle school students in watercolor painting contest in Tehran, 2000.
    \end{itemize}

\vspace{0.015\textwidth}
\hrule
\vspace{0.055\textwidth}
\LHEAD{Teaching Experiences}%
\begin{itemize}
  \item \textbf{IoT Lab Assistant}, 
    \href{http://www.iotlab.wisc.edu}{Internet-of-Things} lab, 
    supervised by Dr. R. Veeramani and T. Yen, Summer 2015.
               \indent Designed tutorials and have worked with Microsoft Band, Pebble Smart Watch, CrazyFlie nanocopter, Parrot AR Drone 2, Intel Galileo Gen1 board, Arduino Yun board, Leap Motion as well as working with IBM Bluemix and Thingsworx platforms.
               \item \textbf{Mathematics and Science Lead}, Program Assistant for \href{http://www.peopleprogram.wisc.edu/}{PEOPEL} program in \href{https://eastweb.madison.k12.wi.us/}{East High School}, Coordinator: Paul Ly Tong Pao, Spring and Fall 2014, Spring 2015.
               \item \textbf{Calculus and Analytic Geometry 1 (Math221)},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. Gloria Mari-Beffa and Dr. Ruifang Song, Department of Mathematics, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Fall 2013.
            \item \textbf{Introduction to Computer Engineering (CS252)},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. Guri Sohi and Dr. Mark Hill, ECE/CS
Department, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Spring 2013.
            \item \textbf{Introduction to Computer Architecture (ECE/CS552)},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. Yu Hen Hu, ECE/CS
Department, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Fall 2012.
               \item \textbf{Advanced Electronic Circuits (ECE342)}, Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. Giri Vekataramanan, ECE Department,
University of Wisconsin-Madison, Fall 2012.
               \item \textbf{\href{http://edgaps.org/gaps/projects/nephrotex/}{Nephrotex} Virtual Internship for Freshman Engineering Students(InterEng101)}, Student Assistant and Design Advisor, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Fall 2012.
               \item \textbf{Persian Language}, Tutor for \href{http://aptlii.global.wisc.edu/}{APTLII} Program, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Summer 2012.
               \item \textbf{Seeing through Engineer Eyes}, 3-week intensive workshop for middle school students, Instructor, University of
Wisconsin-Madison, Madison, WI.
               \item \textbf{Embedded System Design}, Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. A.Ejlali, Computer Engineering Department,
Sharif University of Technology, Spring 2011.
               \item \textbf{VLSI Design},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr.M.Modarresi, Computer Engineering Department, Sharif
University of Technology, Spring 2011.
               \item \textbf{Network Laboratory}, Instructor, Computer Engineering Department, Sharif University of Technology, Spring 2011.
               \item \textbf{Digital Design Laboratory (using Verilog HDL and implementing on Altera and Xilinx FPGAs)},Instructor, Computer Engineering Department, Sharif
University of Technology, Fall 2010.
               \item \textbf{Automated Hardware Design using VHDL},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr.A.Jahanian. Electrical and Computer Engineering Department, Shahid Beheshti University, Fall
2009.
  \item \textbf{Network Laboratory (CCNA-based, Using Packet Tracer)}, 
    Instructor, Electrical and Computer Engineering Department, 
    Shahid Beheshti University, Fall 2009.
\end{itemize}


\vspace{0.015\textwidth}
\hrule
\vspace{0.055\textwidth}
\LHEAD{Selected Academic Projects}%
\begin{itemize}
  \item \textbf {Toyota Driving Automation Natural User Interface}, 
    Under supervision of Dr. B. Mutlu, Summer 2015.
  \item \textbf {Learning Over Joins, using Factorized Machine Learning 
    algorithms for enhancing the join algorithms}, Under supervision of 
    Dr. Jeffrey Naughton and Arun Kumar, Spring 2015.
  \item \textbf {JPEG Image Compression, Spectral Correlation, IIR and FIR Filter Design with Application in ECG, MinMax Equalizer and Windowing using MATLAB as well as A Survey on Image Segmentation using Spectral Clustering}, as Part of ECE630 Course Under Supervision of Dr. Barry Van Veen, Spring 2014.
        \item \textbf {Survey on Community Mining in Social Networks}, CS784 final project, Under supervision of Dr. A. Doan, Spring 2014.
        \item \textbf {Implemented Command Line Interpreter(Shell), Memory Management Module, Kernel Threads in Linux Environment as well as Modifying xv6 Simulator to Support Multi-Thread, and Lottery Scheduling}, as Part of Operating System Course, Under Supervision of Dr. R. Arpaci-dusseau, Fall 2013.
        \item \textbf{Survey on Creating Accelerator for GPU and Converting/Annotating C Benchmark for an Existing Accelerator}, Under supervision of Dr Nam Kim (co-advised by Dr. Katherine (Compton) Morrow), Spring and Summer 2013.
        \item \textbf{DySER, use of accelerators beside OpenSparcT1, on VIRTEX 7}, Under Supervision of Dr. K.Sankaralingam, Fall 2012.
        \item \textbf{Exploiting Heterogeneity in Amazon EC2 Cloud for Better Pricing and Better Availability using CloudMeter Simulator}, Under Supervision of Dr. M. Swift and Dr. S. LU, Fall 2012.
        \item \textbf{Design of a fully 5 stage pipelined MIPS processor with 2-way set associative cache using Verilog \& Synthesized
with Design Compiler}, Under Supervision of Dr. D. Wood, Spring 2012.
        \item \textbf{Designing Lab manual for FPGA Lab using Quartus}, Project Assistant, Under Supervision of J. Krachey, Spring 2012.
        \item \textbf{A Survey on Near-duplicate Video Detection Methods using YouTubeAPI, GoogleAppEngine, Hadoop, and Condor}, Under Supervison of Dr. C. Re, Winter
break 2011-2012.
        \item \textbf{Programming a Robot for Automated Arabidopsis Photography in Study of Roots using Visual C++}, Under Supervision of \emph{Dr. A.H. Asadi}, Fall 2011.
        \item \textbf{Designing as well as Upgrading the Persepolis Research Group (at UW-Madison) Website using Joomla CMS},(A Joint work with
Mohammad Khabbazian), Summer and Fall 2011.
        \item \textbf{Simulation of Reliable SSD-based RAID using DiskSim Simulator},  Under Supervision of Dr.H.Asadi, Fall-
Winter 2010.
               \item \textbf{Simulation-Based Fault Injection for Analyzing Embedded Processors Behavior under EMI and PSD},
Under Supervision of Dr. S.G.Miremadi, Fall 2010.
        \item \textbf{Importing ARM ISA into PTscalar from SimpleScalar}, Under Supervision of Dr. A.Ejlali, Summer 2010.

        \item \textbf{Reliable Core Mapping onto Network-on-Chips using Xmulator}, Under Supervision of Dr. S.G.Miremadi, Spring-
Summer 2010.
                \item \textbf{Implementation of NOC Switches to Tolerate MBU Fault using Xmulator}, Under Supervision of
Dr. S.G.Miremadi, Fall 2009.
                \item \textbf{Evaluation of Multi-Core and Parallelizing a FDTD Simulation Tool Using MDCE Toolkit in MATLAB}, Under Supervision of
Dr. A.Jahangir, Fall 2009.
                \item \textbf{Hardware Implementation of a Fast Improved Decimal Multiplier Using VHDL},Under Supervision of
Dr. A.Jahanian, June-September 2009.
                \item \textbf{Implementation and Synthesis of MIPS-R2000 using VHDL and LeonardoSpectrum}, Under Supervision of
Dr. A.Jahanian, Spring 2009.
    \end{itemize}

\LHEAD{Skills}%
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Programming Languages}: Java, R, C, Python, Visual 
    C\#.net, C++, Visual C++.net, Assembly, SQL.
    \item \textbf{Hardware Programming}: Verilog, VHDL, Verilog-A, 
    System C, CUDA-C programming for GPU devices.
    \item \textbf{Synthesis Tools}: Altera Quartus, XilinX ISE, Leonardo 
    Spectrum, Design Compiler.
    \item \textbf{GPU}: GPGPU-Sim, GPUOcelot, HPCToolkit, TAU, CUDA 
    Toolkit, Nvidia Visual Profiler, Gem5-GPU.
    \item \textbf{Simulation Tools}:  ModelSim, CacheSim, PSpice, HSpice, 
    HSIM, Packet Tracer, Ethereal Network Analyzer, LEDIT, Intel Pin 
    Tools, Intel VTune, Gem5, MATLAB.
    \item \textbf{Web Design Tools and Languages}: HTML, CSS, JavaScript, 
    Joomla!, Wordpress, DreamWeaver.
    \item \textbf{Operating Systems}: OSX Mavericks, Linux(Ubuntu \& 
    Redhat) and Microsoft Windows7/8.
    \item Also Familiar with: Shiny, TextBlob, NLTK, JSON, jQuery, MPI and 
    MATLAB-MPI, Twitter API, Hadoop, Condor, YouTubeAPI, Google 
    Visualization API, bash scripting, Visual Studio, Eclipse, LaTeX, 
    Ruby-on-Rails, git, Heroku, VMWare/VirtualBox, Kernel Programming.
\end{itemize}

\LHEAD{Selected Graduate Courses}%
\begin{itemize}
  \item \textbf{Big Data Systems}, \emph{Dr. A. Akella}, CS838, Fall 2015.
  \item \textbf{Theory and Methods of Network Analysis}, \emph{Dr. K. Rohe}, Stat992, Fall 2015.
  \item \textbf{Database Seminar}, \emph{Dr. J. Patel}, CS900, Spring 2015.
  \item \textbf{Human-Computer Interaction}, \emph{S. Andrist}, CS570, Spring 2015.
  \item \textbf{Advanced Database Management Systems}, \emph{Dr. J. Naughton}, CS764, Spring 2015.
  \item \textbf{Database Management Systems}, \emph{Dr. J. Naughton}, CS564, Fall 2015.
  \item \textbf{Introduction to Artificial Intelligence}, \emph{ Dr. J. Zhu}, CS540, Fall 2014.
  \item \textbf{Introductory, Intermediate and Advance Data Analysis using R},\emph{ J. Gillett}, STAT692, Spring 2014.
  \item \textbf{All of Signal Processing},\emph{ Dr. B. Van Veen}, ECE630, Spring 2014.
  \item \textbf{Machine Learning},\emph{ Dr. D. Page}, Audited, CS760, Spring 2014.
  \item \textbf{Data Models and Database Languages},\emph{ Dr. A. Doan}, CS784, Fall 2013.
  \item \textbf{Introduction to Operating Systems}, \emph{Dr. R. Arpaci-Dusseau}, CS537, Fall 2013.
  \item \textbf{Advance Computer Architecture  II}, \emph{Dr. M. Lipasti}, CS/ECE757, Spring 2013.
  \item \textbf{Advance Computer Architecture  I}, \emph{Dr. K. Sankaralingam}, CS/ECE752, Fall 2012.
  \item \textbf{Distributed Systems}, \emph{Dr. S. Lu}, CS537, Fall 2012.
  \item \textbf{Digital System Design and Synthesis} \emph{E. Hoffman}, ECE551 Spring 2012.
    \item \textbf{Introduction to Computer Architecture} \emph{Dr. D. Wood}, CS/ECE552 Spring 2012.
    \item \textbf{Topics in Applied Mathematics}, \emph{Dr. A.H. Assadi}, MATH801, Fall 2011.
    \item \textbf{Verification of Reactive Systems}, \emph{Dr. M. Izadi}, Spring 2011.
    \item \textbf{Wireless Communication}, \emph{Dr. A. Hemmatyar}, Fall 2010.
    \item \textbf{M.Sc. Seminar}, \emph{Dr. S.G. Miremadi}, Fall 2010.
    \item \textbf{Advanced Computer Networks}, \emph{Dr. K. Mizanian}, Fall 2010.
    \item \textbf{Advanced Storage System}, \emph{Dr. H. Asadi}, Fall 2010.
    \item \textbf{Advanced Fault-tolerant Systems}, \emph{Dr. S.G. Miremadi}, Spring 2010.
    \item \textbf{Embedded System Design}, \emph{Dr. A. Ejlali}, Spring 2010.
    \item \textbf{Reconfigurable Computing}, \emph{Dr. H. Assadi}, Spring 2010.
    \item \textbf{Testability}, \emph{Dr. S. Hessabi}, Fall 2009.
    \item \textbf{Fault-Tolerant Systems}, \emph{Dr. S.G. Miremadi}, Fall 2009.
\end{itemize}

\vspace{0.015\textwidth}
\hrule
\vspace{0.055\textwidth}
\LHEAD{Publications}%
\begin{itemize}
  \item     A. Kumar, M. Jalal, B. Yan, J. F. Naughton, J. M. Patel:
\textbf{Demonstration of Santoku: Optimizing Machine Learning over Normalized Data}. PVLDB 8(12): 1864-1875, 2015.
        \item A. Sangari, M. Jalal, H. Ardalani, E.S. Selen, H.T. Dashti, M. Mahdavi, Amir H. Assadi,\textbf{ High-throughput Data Collection and Automated Imaging}, Annual Eye Research Institute Vision
Science/Visual Art Poster and Gallery Session, October 2011 (Poster Version).
        \item M. Jalal, Z. Shirmohammadi, A. Patooghy, S. G. Miremadi, \href{http://connection.ebscohost.com/c/articles/65648209/evaluation-application-mapping-network-on-chips}{Evaluation of Application Mapping for Network-on-
Chips}, Accepted in Real-time and Embedded Systems(RTES'10), 2010.
        \item Z. Shirmohammadi, M. Jalal, A. Patooghy, S. G. Miremadi, \href{http://connection.ebscohost.com/c/articles/65648201/reconfigurable-switch-architecture-enhance-reliability-network-on-chips}{A Reconfigurable Switch Architecture to Enhance
Reliability of Network-on-Chips}, Accepted in Real-time and Embedded Systems(RTES'10), 2010.
\end{itemize}

\vspace{0.015\textwidth}
%\hrule
\vspace{0.055\textwidth}
\LHEAD{Curricular Activities}%
\begin{itemize}
    \item \href{http://research.cs.wisc.edu/wacm/officers.html}{WACM}: Activity Chair, 2013-2015; Mentoring Chair, 2015-2016. 
    \item \href{http://sacm.cs.wisc.edu/}{SACM}: Social Chair, 2014-2015. 
    \item \href{http://chialphauw.org/Chi_Alpha/Welcome.html}{Madison CHI ALPHA}: Reader in tour of Madison and member.
    \item {Society of Women Engineer} : UW-Madison SWE collegiate member,2014-2015 academic year.
    \item {ACM}: Active student membership, 2014-2015 academic year.
    \item {Systers}: Member, Starting fall 2014.
    \item {Hoofers Sailing Club}: Member, Summer 2015.
\end{itemize}

\vspace{0.015\textwidth}
\hrule
\vspace{0.055\textwidth}
\LHEAD{Langauges}%
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Persian}: Native
    \item \textbf{English}: Fluent
    \item \textbf{French}: Intermediate
    \item \textbf{Italian}: Familiar
    \item \textbf{Arabic}: Familiar
\end{itemize}

\vspace{0.015\textwidth}
\hrule
\vspace{0.055\textwidth}
\LHEAD{Interests}%
\begin{itemize}
  \item Sailing
  \item Cooking
    \item Swimming
    \item Badminton
    \item Dancing
    \item Watercolor Painting
    \item Portrait Drawing
    \item Verse Writing
    \item talentbuddy.co
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: what should I remove from the code so that the right rectangle (margin) and the top rectangle in the first page are removed? I don't want to have them